# Stuck with proof of Feller's basic Limit theorem for Markov chains - just a small calculation away!

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, ergodic-theory

I have been following Feller's proof of Basic Limit theorem (page 336 and following, *An introduction to probability theory and its applications*, W. Feller). It's basically the one that says that the probability of a being in a state of an ergodic chain converges to a stationary value in the long time limit and this value is $1/\mu$, the mean recurrence time. I am almost done. I got stuck with one of the final arguments, at page 338.
[image]

where $f_i$ are numbers such that $\sum_{i}f_i=1$ and $0\leq f_i\leq 1$. $\mu$ is defined as $\mu=\sum_i if_i$. Variables $u_i$ represent the probability of the stochastic event to verify at trial number $i$, while $f_i$ represent the probability of seeing the event **for the first time** after $i$ trials. As such, you have the relation called by the book (11.1): $u_n=u_{n-1}f_1+u_{n-2}f_2+...+u_0f_n$. But now if I sum over $n$ as the book says, I get something like:
$$\sum_n^N u_n=(u_0f_1)+(u_1f_1+u_0f_2)+...+(u_{N-1}f_1+..+u_0f_n)=$$
$$u_0(1-\rho_N)+u_1(1-\rho_{N-1})+...+u_{N-1}(1-\rho_{1})$$. Bringing all terms with just $u_n$ to the side of the summation at the top left I am left with a $$u_N=u_N\rho_0=-(u_0\rho_N+u_1\rho_{N-1}+...+u_{N-1}\rho_{1})$$. What the book says it's one appears to be zero to me. It's a real pity, only this calculation and I am done understanding the theorem ! I give a link to the book if you need it: https://it.1lib.to/book/966574/a18835

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget the limits of summation!

The identity obtained is
$$\sum_{n=1}^N u_n=(u_0f_1)+(u_1f_1+u_0f_2)+...+(u_{N-1}f_1+..+u_0f_N)=$$
$$u_0(1-\rho_N)+u_1(1-\rho_{N-1})+...+u_{N-1}(1-\rho_{1}) \,.$$
Note that $u_0$ does not appear on the Left hand side. Since $u_0=1$, that explains the missing 1.

When encountering such contradictions, checking for small $N$ will usually clear things up.